# select artificial values from oracle database

Tags: oracle, alias, rows

This may sound like a strange question, but I assure you that it has a purpose. Right now, I have this "useless" subquery:

```
select distinct
  'gallery' as gallery,
  'echo' as echo,
  'turnitin' as turnitin,
  'assignment' assignment,
  'assessment' as assessment
from table_x;
```

Obviously, it returns the results:

```
GALLERY,ECHO,TURNITIN,ASSIGNMENT,ASSESSMENT
gallery,echo,turnitin,assignment,assessment
```

What I really want is something like:

```
DATA_TYPE
gallery
echo
turnitin
assignment
assessment
```

This will allow me to manipulate the the data as I need to when using it as a subquery. I only have read access to the database, so I'd like to keep it within a single `SELECT` statement. How might I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNPIVOT works well here:

```
with t as (
select 'gallery' as gallery,
  'echo' as echo,
  'turnitin' as turnitin,
  'assignment' assignment,
  'assessment' as assessment
from dual
)
select data_type 
  from t
unpivot (
  data_type for column1 in (gallery, echo, turnitin, assignment, assessment)
)

DATA_TYPE
---------
gallery
echo
turnitin
assignment
assessment
```

Comment: The other one works, but this way is much more clear.

Comment: With less SELECTing going on, this method might be more efficient than mine, although in the real world I imagine you'd probably have to be creating an awful lot of records to notice the improvement. I think my method would actually be clearer and easier to manage if you were creating a lot of records, but I guess that's probably a matter of taste/opinion. Curious by the way - any particular reason why you wouldn't just create a table?

Comment: @Bacs Read-only access to this particular database :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
with temp_table as
(select 'gallery' data_type from dual
 union
 select 'echo' data_type from dual
 union
 select 'turnitin' data_type from dual
 -- etc
)
select data_type
from temp_table;
```

Comment: You are the wind beneath my wings.